# How to create a NetCDF file with Albers conical equal area projection in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, numpy, pyproj, array

I was wondering how to create a NetCDF file with the following dimensions and variables;

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF4 data model, file format HDF5):
    Conventions: CF-1.7
    dimensions(sizes): y(512), n2(2), x(512)
    variables(dimensions): int64 valid_time(), int64 start_time(), float64 y(y), float64 y_bounds(y,n2), float64 x(x), float64 x_bounds(x,n2), float64 precipitation(y,x), int8 proj()
    groups:
```

Specifically, the data and variables are;

```
valid_time
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int64 valid_time()
    long_name: End of accumulation period
    standard_name: time
    units: seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = ()
filling off


start_time
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int64 start_time()
    long_name: Start of accumulation period
    units: seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = ()
filling off

y
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 y(y)
    standard_name: projection_y_coordinate
    units: km
    bounds: y_bounds
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (512,)
filling off 

y data; array([ 127.75,  127.25,  126.75, ... , -126.75, -127.25, -127.75])

y_bounds
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 y_bounds(y, n2)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (512, 2)
filling off

y_bounds data
array([[ 128. ,  127.5],
       [ 127.5,  127. ],
       [ 127. ,  126.5],
       ...,
       [-126.5, -127. ],
       [-127. , -127.5],
       [-127.5, -128. ]])

x
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 x(x)
    standard_name: projection_x_coordinate
    units: km
    bounds: x_bounds
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (512,)
filling off

x data; array([-127.75, -127.25, -126.75,..., 126.75,  127.25, 127.75])

x_bounds
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 x_bounds(x, n2)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (512, 2)
filling off

x_bounds data; 
array([[-128. , -127.5],
       [-127.5, -127. ],
       [-127. , -126.5],
       ...,
       [ 126.5,  127. ],
       [ 127. ,  127.5],
       [ 127.5,  128. ]])

precipitation 
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int16 precipitation(y, x)
    long_name: Accumulated precipitation
    standard_name: precipitation_amount
    units: kg m-2
    add_offset: 0.0
    scale_factor: 0.05
    _FillValue: -1
    grid_mapping: proj
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (512, 512)
filling off

precipitation data; my_array which is a 2d (512,512) array

<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int8 proj()
    grid_mapping_name: albers_conical_equal_area
    standard_parallel: [-36.3 -39.4]
    longitude_of_central_meridian: 144.752
    latitude_of_projection_origin: -37.852
    false_easting: 0.0
    false_northing: 0.0
    semi_major_axis: 6378137.0
    semi_minor_axis: 6356752.31414
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = ()
filling off
```

I tried to create the NetCDF file using the following scripts, but it is not complete and didn't work.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset    # Note: python is case-sensitive!
import numpy as np

ncfile = Dataset('precip.nc',mode='w',format='NETCDF4') 

#create dimensions
y_dim = ncfile.createDimension('y', 512)     # y axis
x_dim = ncfile.createDimension('x', 512)    # x axis
n2 = ncfile.createDimension('n2', 2) 

# Define variables 
valid_time = ncfile.createVariable('valid_time', np.int64, 
('valid_time',))
long_name= 'End of accumulation period'
standard_name= 'time'
units= 'seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        
start_time = ncfile.createVariable('start_time', np.int64, ('start_time',))
long_name= 'Start of accumulation period'
units= 'seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        
y = ncfile.createVariable('y', np.float64, ('y',))
y.units = 'km'
standard_name: projection_y_coordinate   
y_bounds=ncfile.createVariable('y_bounds', np.float64, ('y_bounds',))

x= ncfile.createVariable('x', np.float64, ('x',))
x.units = 'km'
standard_name: projection_x_coordinate  
x_bounds=ncfile.createVariable('x_bounds', np.float64, ('x_bounds',))
        
precipitation = ncfile.createVariable('precipitation',np.float64, 
('y','x')) # note: unlimited dimension is leftmost
plong_name= 'Accumulated precipitation'
standard_name= 'precipitation_amount'
units: 'mm'

proj=ncfile.createVariable('proj',np.int8,())
grid_mapping_name= 'albers_conical_equal_area'
longitude_of_central_meridian= 144.752
latitude_of_projection_origin= -37.852
false_easting= 0.0
false_northing= 0.0
semi_major_axis= 6378137.0
semi_minor_axis= 6356752.31414

# write data
nys = len(y_dim); nxs = len(x_dim); ntimes = 1
y[:] = y 
x[:] = x 
precipitation[:,:] = my_array 

ncfile.close()
```

Comment: What is the format of the original CRS?

Comment: Hello @snowman2 and thanks for your reply. I have just this information, but the spatial data is for Melbourne, Australia. I think it must be GDA94.           _CoordinateTransformType = "Projection"; _CoordinateAxisTypes = "GeoX GeoY";

Comment: Hello @snowman2, regarding the above question, I have a NetCDF which one of its variables is precipitation. The data of precipitation is a 2d array (512,512), and its dtype is int32. I need to change the dtype to float64. Rewriting the NetCDF is difficult for me. Could you please let me know how I can change the dtype of precipitation. I tried this code but it didnt work,    import xarray as xr
ds=xr.open_dataset('file.nc')
ds.variables['precipitation'].values = ds.variables['precipitation'].values.astype('float64') . I think I need to change the variable, not the values.

Comment: Can you open up a separate question for that? My guess is that the encoding has the original data type.

Comment: Per https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#variables-in-a-netcdf-file use `'f8'` as in `precipitation = ncfile.createVariable('precipitation','f8', 
('y','x')) `

Comment: That NetCDF code looks wrong-- in several cases, the attributes aren't assigned to the datasets's variables, but simply to regular python variables that are unused.  E.g  `standard_name= 'time'` should be `valid_time.standard_name= 'time'`  otherwise `standard_time` gets rewritten multiple times and not passed to the particular dataset variables as attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete match, but your NETCDF4 code needs some changes to be functional:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset    # Note: python is case-sensitive!
import numpy as np

ncfile = Dataset('precip.nc',mode='w',format='NETCDF4') 

#create dimensions
y_dim = ncfile.createDimension('y', 512)     # y axis
x_dim = ncfile.createDimension('x', 512)    # x axis
n2 = ncfile.createDimension('n2', 2) 

# Define variables 
valid_time = ncfile.createVariable('valid_time', np.int64,)
valid_time.long_name= 'End of accumulation period'
valid_time.standard_name= 'time'
valid_time.units= 'seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        
start_time = ncfile.createVariable('start_time', np.int64,)
start_time.long_name= 'Start of accumulation period'
start_time.units= 'seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        
y = ncfile.createVariable('y', np.float64, ('y',))
y.units = 'km'
y.standard_name= 'projection_y_coordinate'   
y_bounds=ncfile.createVariable('y_bounds', np.float64,('y','n2'))

x= ncfile.createVariable('x', np.float64, ('x',))
x.units = 'km'
x.standard_name= 'projection_x_coordinate'  
x_bounds=ncfile.createVariable('x_bounds', np.float64,('x','n2'))
        
precipitation = ncfile.createVariable('precipitation','f8', ('y','x')) # note: unlimited dimension is leftmost
precipitation.long_name= 'Accumulated precipitation'
precipitation.standard_name= 'precipitation_amount'
precipitation.units= 'mm'

proj=ncfile.createVariable('proj',np.int8,())
proj.grid_mapping_name= 'albers_conical_equal_area'
proj.longitude_of_central_meridian= 144.752
proj.latitude_of_projection_origin= -37.852
proj.false_easting= 0.0
proj.false_northing= 0.0
proj.semi_major_axis= 6378137.0
proj.semi_minor_axis= 6356752.31414

# write data # 
nys = len(y_dim); nxs = len(x_dim); ntimes = 1
y[:] = np.arange(nys) 
x[:] = np.arange(nxs)
precipitation[:,:] = np.random.random([nys,nxs]) 

ncfile.close()
```

Which produces a file of this structure as reported by `ncdump -h precip.nc`:

```
netcdf precip {
dimensions:
    y = 512 ;
    x = 512 ;
    n2 = 2 ;
variables:
    int64 valid_time ;
        valid_time:long_name = "End of accumulation period" ;
        valid_time:standard_name = "time" ;
        valid_time:units = "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" ;
    int64 start_time ;
        start_time:long_name = "Start of accumulation period" ;
        start_time:units = "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" ;
    double y(y) ;
        y:units = "km" ;
        y:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
    double y_bounds(y, n2) ;
    double x(x) ;
        x:units = "km" ;
        x:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
    double x_bounds(x, n2) ;
    double precipitation(y, x) ;
        precipitation:long_name = "Accumulated precipitation" ;
        precipitation:standard_name = "precipitation_amount" ;
        precipitation:units = "mm" ;
    byte proj ;
        proj:grid_mapping_name = "albers_conical_equal_area" ;
        proj:longitude_of_central_meridian = 144.752 ;
        proj:latitude_of_projection_origin = -37.852 ;
        proj:false_easting = 0. ;
        proj:false_northing = 0. ;
        proj:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
        proj:semi_minor_axis = 6356752.31414 ;
}
```

I simulated some data, but you'd need to create your actual numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dave X, now the codes are working.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using pyproj: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs_cf.html

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> crs = CRS("ESRI:102008")
>>> pprint(crs.to_cf())
{'crs_wkt': 'PROJCRS["North_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",DATUM["North '
            'American Datum 1983",ELLIPSOID["GRS '
            '1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],CONVERSION["North_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",METHOD["Albers '
            'Equal Area",ID["EPSG",9822]],PARAMETER["Latitude of false '
            'origin",40,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8821]],PARAMETER["Longitude '
            'of false '
            'origin",-96,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8822]],PARAMETER["Latitude '
            'of 1st standard '
            'parallel",20,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8823]],PARAMETER["Latitude '
            'of 2nd standard '
            'parallel",60,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8824]],PARAMETER["Easting '
            'at false '
            'origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8826]],PARAMETER["Northing '
            'at false '
            'origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8827]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],USAGE[SCOPE["Not '
            'known."],AREA["North America - onshore and offshore: Canada - '
            'Alberta; British Columbia; Manitoba; New Brunswick; Newfoundland '
            'and Labrador; Northwest Territories; Nova Scotia; Nunavut; '
            'Ontario; Prince Edward Island; Quebec; Saskatchewan; Yukon. '
            'United States (USA) - Alabama; Alaska (mainland); Arizona; '
            'Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; '
            'Georgia; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; '
            'Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; '
            'Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; '
            'New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; '
            'Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South '
            'Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; '
            'Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; '
            'Wyoming."],BBOX[23.81,-172.54,86.46,-47.74]],ID["ESRI",102008]]',
 'false_easting': 0.0,
 'false_northing': 0.0,
 'geographic_crs_name': 'NAD83',
 'grid_mapping_name': 'albers_conical_equal_area',
 'horizontal_datum_name': 'North American Datum 1983',
 'inverse_flattening': 298.257222101,
 'latitude_of_projection_origin': 40.0,
 'longitude_of_central_meridian': -96.0,
 'longitude_of_prime_meridian': 0.0,
 'prime_meridian_name': 'Greenwich',
 'projected_crs_name': 'North_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic',
 'reference_ellipsoid_name': 'GRS 1980',
 'semi_major_axis': 6378137.0,
 'semi_minor_axis': 6356752.314140356,
 'standard_parallel': (20.0, 60.0)}
```

EDIT: You may also be interested in xarray/rioxarray

- https://github.com/pydata/xarray/
- https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/